# Fetch list data in rich textbox and save data from same rich box to list

Tags: rich-text

I want to perform this-

1. Fetch SharePoint list data to a rich text box
2. Then save the data from the rich box back to the list

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you performing the activity in a same list or different lists? If different lists, say you are fetching data from rich text field Field AAA of list XXX and saving the data in rich text field BBB of list YYY.

Comment: same list, i want to give edit option to user, so data can be edited in rich text format and get save in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a Multiple line of text column in the list for your requirement and you will get an option to make the field as Rich text or enhanced rich text. Refer the links below for further details.

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/start-to-learn-sharepoint-2

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Site-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7#__toc277149822

Comment: List is already created with rich textbox and data is already filled. i want to fetch that data in such way that user can edit it using rich textbox toolbar. i tried to fetch the data using javascript in textbox. however its showing data in html format with div tag